# Cannot configure the publishing extension for gradle

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle v3.4 with the following build.gradle file.  However, I get the error copied below with any tasks.  Any thoughts on what might be misconfigured in the build.gradle file?

**error**

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'some-test'.
> Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.
```

The error points to where the publishing task begins.

**build.gradle**

```
group 'some.group'
version '0.0.1' //-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin:'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username project.properties['nexusUsername']
                password project.properties['nexusPassword']
            }
            url project.properties['nexus.url.snapshot']
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0'
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.4'
    }
}

if (!JavaVersion.current().java8Compatible) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Must be built with Java 8 or higher")
}

mainClassName = "com.some.project.some.class"

defaultTasks 'clean', 'build', 'shadowJar', 'install'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username project.properties['nexusUsername']
            password project.properties['nexusPassword']
        }
        url project.properties['nexus.url.snapshot']
    }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

def grpcVersion = '1.1.2'
def log4j2Version = '2.8.1'
def configVersion = '1.3.1'
def jacksonVersion = '2.8.7'

dependencies {
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-netty:${grpcVersion}"
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: jacksonVersion
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: jacksonVersion
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: jacksonVersion

    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: log4j2Version
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: log4j2Version
    compile 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:1.1.33.Fork26'
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk16', version: '1.46'
    compile "com.typesafe:config:${configVersion}"

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.3'
}


sourceSets {
    main {
        proto {
            srcDir '../../proto' // In addition to the default 'src/main/proto'
        }
        java {
        }
    }
    test {
        proto {
            srcDir '../../proto' // In addition to the default 'src/test/proto'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.2.0'
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {
                // To generate deprecated interfaces and static bindService method,
                // turn the enable_deprecated option to true below:
                option 'enable_deprecated=false'
            }
        }
    }
}


idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("${projectDir}/build/generated/source/proto/main/java");
        sourceDirs += file("${projectDir}/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc");
    }
}



jar {
    manifest {
           attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'com.some.project.some.class'
        )
    }
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'commons-java'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}

artifacts {
    archives shadowJar
}


publishing {
    publications {
        shadow(MavenPublication) {
            from components.shadow
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "someuser"
                password "somepassword"
            }
            url "http://nexus.somewhere.com/repository/some-test-snapshots/"
        }
    }
}

tasks.publish.dependsOn 'shadowJar'

startScripts.enabled = false
```

Comment: Can you provide a full MCVE project e. g. on GitHub?

Comment: @Vampire - the whole build file is above - is there anything else you are looking for.  This is a project that builds & I can publish locally (maven repo) - I just cannot publish to remote repo as soon as I add the publishing task.  When I change publishing to publishing.publications, I do not get the error (but I still need to specify the remote nexus credentials info in any case)

Comment: Well, I don't instantly see the error, that is why I asked for whether you can provide an MCVE so that I can see the error locally.

Comment: @Vampire - I appreciate the response.  The moment I take out the publishing task, I can run all the gradle tasks (except for remote publishing).  I can add more output from the debug statement shortly.

Comment: What do you mean by "take out the publishing task"? Take out from where?

Comment: Also maybe you should not use the `maven` *and* the `maven-publish` task. Maybe that is the problem already. Both serve the same purpose, publishing to a maven repository. `maven` is the old and stable one, `maven-publish` is the future, but still incubating. I'd use the latter one though.

Comment: thanks @Vampire - i believe the issue was reading the properties inside the build.gradle - once i hard coded the values, the error went away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was how I was reading the properties - also, I no longer use both maven and maven-publish plugins (I am using maven-publish only).  I am currently able to publish to nexus successfully.